# Android scrollindicators style / color android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
android:scrollIndicators="top|bottom"
```

does provide scroll indicators, but they are barely visible at all.

Screenshot of barely visible Scrollindicators

[image: Screenshot of barely visible Scrollindicators]

What theme/style color are they using, or how can I assign a custom color?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the scroll bar by changing its width and setting a custom shape.
Add following tags in your scroll view

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" // set as required..
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/vertical_scrollview_track"
android:scrollbarSize="20dp"// set as required width..
```

**Create following drawable in your drawable folder**

**vertical_scrollview_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#E2E0EB" />
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="#b3a9a9" />
<size android:width="15dp" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

change colour as required.

Comment: This is NOT about the scrollbar, but about the scroll indicators.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

As with SwitchCompat's track, a low opacity / high transparency version of colorForeground is used. Setting it to full white (or black on light backgrounds) makes the scrollindicators at least a bit more visible before someone finds the real solution.